# Is there any IN Operator in VB.net functions like the one in SQL

Tags: .net, vb.net, operators

Is there any function or operator like:

```
        If RoleName in ( "Val1",  "Val2" ,"Val2" ) Then
        'Go
    End If
```

Instead of:

```
    If RoleName = "Val1" Or RoleName = "Val2" Or RoleName = "Val2" Then
        'Go
    End If
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try using an  array and then you can use the Contains extension:

```
Dim s() As String = {"Val1", "Val2", "Val3"}
If s.Contains(RoleName) Then
  'Go      
End If
```

Or without the declaration line:

```
If New String() {"Val1", "Val2", "Val3"}.Contains(RoleName) Then
  'Go
End If
```

From the OP, if the Contains extension is not available, you can try this:

```
If Array.IndexOf(New String() {"Val1", "Val2", "Val3"}, RoleName) > -1 Then
  'Go
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's throwing :
'contains' is not a member of 'system.array',
I have found a solution, please update your answer:
`If (Array.IndexOf(New String() {"Val1", "Val2", "Val3"}, RoleName) > -1) Then`

Comment: @Ala Then you probably don't have a reference to System.Linq in your Project - References list.

Comment: @Ala: Maybe you're missing the imports statement at the top of the file: `Imports System.Linq`?

Comment: @Meta-Knight, Yes, Exactly using `System.Linq` has solved the error `'contains' is not a member of 'system.array'`.

Answer (score 17):

You can use Contains as shown by LarsTech, but it's also very easy to add an `In` extension method:

```
Public Module Extensions

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function [In](Of T)(value As T, ParamArray collectionValues As T()) As Boolean
        Return collectionValues.Contains(value)
    End Function

End Module
```

You can use it like this:

```
If RoleName.In("Val1", "Val2", "Val3") Then
    'Go
End If
```

Answer (score 16):

You could also use a `Select..Case` statement:

```
Select Case RoleName 
    Case "Val1", "Val2", "Val3"
        ' Whatever
End Select
```

Comment: +1 for readability, even if it's a bit boring compared to the other answers :)