# Can you use an array in an If statement?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I have a series of conditional `If` statements used for different routines.

I'm looking for a way to put those conditions in an array. All conditions will be OR or AND.

```vb
If _value = 1 or _value = 2 or _value = 4 or _value = 5 then
'do something
Elseif   _value = 21 or _value = 22 or _value = 24 or _value = 25 then
'do something
Else
'Do something
End If
```

I'm looking for something like:

```vb
If _value = OR(Array1) then
'do something
Elseif   _value = Or(Array2) then
'do something
Else
'Do something
End If
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Depends on your values? Can you check a range, i.e., `If value >= 1 and value <=10`? Or you can write your check function that takes a `ParamArray` and then call that in the `If`?

Comment: I think the "or" case is already addressed.  You say that a condition might be "and", but you don't explain what the semantics would be.  Can you elaborate?  It could probably be done with Linq's `All`.  Arrays implement `IEnumerable(Of T)` so you can use `All` on an array.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest the following:

```
If {1, 2, 4, 5}.Contains(_value) Then
    'do something
ElseIf {21, 22, 24, 25}.Contains(_value) Then
    'do something
Else
    'do something
End If
```

You'd need to ensure you have an `Imports System.Linq` for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

For the OR operators you can use Array.IndexOf and see if the return value is -1 like so:

```
Dim Array1() As Integer = {1, 2, 3}
If Array.IndexOf(Array1, _value) > -1 Then
  Console.WriteLine("CODE HERE")
End If
```

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513586/is-there-any-in-operator-in-vb-net-functions-like-the-one-in-sql) if you need more information.
Hope this helps!